# How to exclude product(s) from search result programatically in Magento

Tags: magento, events

I'm trying to exclude products from populating the search result.
It seems to be working fine on my localhost but not on clients dev server.
I'm observing the event 
`catalog_block_product_list_collection`

and in observer method, in the end is this code:

`$observer->getCollection()
 ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('nin' => array_keys($_excludeProducts)))
 ->clear()
 ->load();`

which works for catalog as well and search result list but for the moment not on search result list on clients dev server.
Any guidance/help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: Debugging this method gives me an empty collection but still the data is populating from somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed the approach and used another event: `catalog_product_collection_load_before`

found better method to implement the approach with less code. #optimization

`$excludeIds = array(2,3,4); //$excludeIds mixed`

`$observer->getCollection()
  ->addIdFilter($excludeIds, true); //exclude = true`

The event also helps in keeping the correct items count on toolbar as it is dispatched before collection load.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue when trying to filter this collection using this event.
Do you have flat categories and flat products set the same in both environments? In my case, my code would only work with flat tables OFF, since I was using joining other EAV attributes.
In your case, if you are using flat, I think you just need to do `addAttributeToFilter()` instead.

In my case, here is what my observer looks like:

```
function onCategoryCollectionLoad($observer) {
    $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCategoryCollection();

    $customerGroupId = (int) Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();

    // hidden_from_groups is an EAV attribute; I couldn't figure out how to make it work with flat because it has a backend_model
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('hidden_from_groups');

    $collection->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('should_be_hidden', "COALESCE(FIND_IN_SET($customerGroupId, {{attribute}}), 0)", 'hidden_from_groups');

    // should_be_hidden is not a real db field (nor EAV attribute); it only exists because of the addExpressionAttributeToSelect() above.
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('should_be_hidden', array('lt' => 1));

    // I don't call $collection->load(); that will get called further down the line.    
}
```

Comment: thanks for the post. this didn't work in my case. the observer i'm using doesn't have this method `getCategoryCollection` i'm on the search result page (catalogsearch). on my local machine its coming up alright after making few changes. I think i'll post that as an answer.

Comment: on client site, categories and products are set to flat but i tried with that as well but still (facepalm) on local its alright but not on clients'. he does have lots of other modules installed though but just can't figure it out which one is interfering.